# Outlook ItemAdd event registered from VSTO plugin and WPF app fires twice

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have two .NET applications: A VSTO plugin for Outlook and a WPF application. Both applications send e-mail with Outlook and need to do something to these sent e-mail items. To that end, both applications use Outlook interop and register the same method to the `ItemAdd` event for the sent mail folder.

Some users only use the VSTO; other users only use the WPF application. However, some users have the VSTO **and** also use the WPF application, and in that case, the method for the `ItemAdd` event is fired twice. I tried to get around this using a Singleton pattern (see below), however it is not working.

Please advise on how I can make it work, such that the `HandleSentMail` method is only fired once, even if the user has both the VSTO and is running the WPF application.

**Registering event**

Both the VSTO and the WPF application use the following code to attach a method `HandleSentMail` to the `ItemAdd` event (in the VSTO, it is placed in the `Ribbon1_Load` method):

```
OutlookInterface.Instance.SentMailItems.ItemAdd -= new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(MailHandler.Instance.HandleSentMail);
OutlookInterface.Instance.SentMailItems.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(MailHandler.Instance.HandleSentMail);
```

**OutlookInterface.cs**

```
public sealed class OutlookInterface {
  /// <summary>
  /// Singleton pattern, see
  /// https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton
  /// </summary>
  private static readonly Lazy<OutlookInterface> lazy = new Lazy<OutlookInterface>(() => new OutlookInterface());

  public static OutlookInterface Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

  public Application MailApplication { get; set; }

  public Items SentMailItems { get; set; }

  private OutlookInterface() {
    MailApplication = new Application();
    SentMailItems = MailApplication.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
  }
}
```

**MailHandler.cs**

```
public sealed class MailHandler {
  /// <summary>
  /// Singleton pattern, see
  /// https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton
  /// </summary>
  private static readonly Lazy<WorkZoneMailHandler> lazy = new Lazy<WorkZoneMailHandler>(() => new WorkZoneMailHandler());

  public static WorkZoneMailHandler Instance {
    get {
      return lazy.Value;
    }
  }

  public async void HandleSentMail(object item) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have some kind of globally accessible db/list of processed messages and store the entry ids of the messages one of the two apps processed so that the other won't pick it up, or, better yet, give priority to one app over another (e.g. addin takes priority over the standalone app). You can use a named mutex for that in the HandleSentMail method - addin can open the mutex on startup (and close it on shutdown), but the standalone app can check if the mutex has already been opened, and if it was, skip processing:

```cs
Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "YourCustomMutex", out bool createdNew);
if (createdNew)
{
    // The application is not already running.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I understand your suggestion, I am to have two `HandleSentMail` methods: one for the VSTO and one for the WPF app. However (and I failed to add this detail), the `OutlookInterface` and `MailHandler` classes are in separate class libraries, that are shared by the VSTO and the WPF app. Could I make your suggestion work without duplicating the `HandleSentMail` code?

Comment: When you create an instance of the (shared) MailHandler class, make its constructor take a boolean parameter that will indicate whether it is a master or a slave. In the latter case, you can run the logic that skips the handler if another handler with the same mutex is active

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find any mechanism which allows detecting the second event you need to handle events on the add-in side and use standard techniques for interprocess communications (for example, [.net remoting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remoting-in-net/)) and connect your WPF application with your VSTO add-in instead. They are both .net applications! When you load Outlook from your WPF application your VSTO add-in is loaded as well, so you can connect to it instead of handling Outlook events. Just add a condition if the add-in is loaded don't subscribe to the events in the code.

You may find Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) helpful in that case, see [Develop Service-Oriented Applications with WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/) for more information.

Comment: As I understand it, you suggest to have the event fire only from the VSTO add-in, and have it handle the sent e-mail from both the VSTO add-in and the WPF application. However, in some cases, users only have the WPF application, and not the VSTO add-in, so how would that work?

Comment: Your WPF application at startup can check whether the COM add-in is installed for Outlook. See the `COMAddIns` property of the `Application` class. So, when Outlook is automated from your WPF application the very first thing is to check whether Outlook is running and then subscribe or not to the events depending on the COM add-in presence.